# Scripts that display static pages in Blogger don't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, blogger, blogspot

I downloaded a template to a Blogger blog and I wanted to remove some parts of a static post details like the tags and author and just want to display the post thumbnail, post title, number of comments and summary of the post. I drew it so it will a lot more understandable. It looks like this by default:

[image]

I found out that in this template, they use this script to display these static pages:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
    <div expr:id='data:post.id'>
      <data:post.body/>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var post_title=&quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;,
        post_url=&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;,
          author_name=&quot;<data:post.author/>&quot;,
            author_url=&quot;<data:post.authorProfileUrl/>&quot;,
              comment=&quot;<data:post.numComments/>&quot;,
                label=&quot;<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'><a expr:href='data:label.url + &quot;?max-results=6&quot;' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a><b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>,&amp;nbsp;</b:if></b:loop>&quot;,
                  time=&quot;<data:post.timestamp/>&quot;;
      readmore(&quot;<data:post.id/>&quot;);
    </script>
  </b:if>
</b:if>
```

Whenever I edit that script, something will go wrong with the static item, it will lose its original look and it looks horrible. Below that code are these:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
  <div class='blog-content-wrapper'>
    <div class='blog-content-inner-wrapper'>
      <header class='post-header'>
        <h3 class='gdlr-blog-title'>
          <a expr:href='data:post.link'>
            <data:post.title/>
          </a>
        </h3>
        <div class='gdlr-blog-info gdlr-title-font gdlr-info'>
          <div class='clear'/>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class='gdlr-blog-content'>
        <data:post.body/>
      </div>
      <div class='single-post-bottom-info'>
        <div class='share-this-post social-icons-wrapper'>
          <a class='facebook' expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url' name='fb_share' target='_blank'>
            <i class='fa fa-facebook'/>
          </a>
          <a class='twitter' expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'>
            <i class='fa fa-twitter'/>
          </a>
          <a class='google' expr:href='&quot;https://plus.google.com/share?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'>
            <i class='fa fa-google-plus'/>
          </a>
          <a class='tumblr' expr:href='&quot;http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=&quot;+ data:post.url' target='_blank'>
            <i class='fa fa-tumblr'/>
          </a>
          <a class='linkedin' expr:href='&quot;http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=&quot;+ data:post.url' target='_blank'>
            <i class='fa fa-linkedin'/>
          </a>
          <a class='stumbleupon' expr:href='&quot;http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=&quot;+ data:post.url' target='_blank'>
            <i class='fa fa-stumbleupon'/>
          </a>
          <a class='digg' expr:href='&quot;http://digg.com/submit?url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank'>
            <i class='fa fa-digg'/>
          </a>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class='gdlr-post-author'>
          <h3 class='post-author-title'>
            About Post Author
          </h3>
          <div class='clear'/>
          <div class='post-author-avartar'>
            <img alt='' class='avatar avatar-125 photo' expr:src='data:post.authorPhoto.url' src='http://i.imgur.com/hgQVqzg.jpg' style='width:125px;'/>                
          </div>
          <div class='post-author-content'>
            <h4 class='post-author'>
              <a expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' rel='author'>
                <data:post.author/>
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class='clear'/>
        </div>
        <div class='gdlr-related-post-widget'>
          <h3 class='related-post-title'>
            You may also like
          </h3>
          <div id='related-posts'>
            <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
              <script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=related_results_labels&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
            </b:loop>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
              removeRelatedDuplicates();printRelatedLabels(&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39;);
            </script>
          </div>
          <div class='clear'>
          </div>
          <div class='clear'>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
  <div class='blog-content-wrapper'>
    <div class='blog-content-inner-wrapper'>
      <header class='post-header'>
        <h3 class='gdlr-blog-title'>
          <a expr:href='data:post.link'>
            <data:post.title/>
          </a>
        </h3>
        <div class='gdlr-blog-info gdlr-title-font gdlr-info'>
          <div class='clear'/>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class='gdlr-blog-content'>
        <data:post.body/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:if>
```

Whenever I edit something on the static `<b:if>`, *nothing* happens to the page. Again, my problem is that I cannot modify anything in this static page.

I really don't know how to do this so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You only posted it here and on r/javascript because you saw "javascript" in the middle, right? Seems that the code you posted isn't valid (e.g.: the part next to `printRelatedLabels` is invalid even if the HTML is unescaped). Based on your "I downloaded a template" maybe is helpful if you show where you downloaded it so we can understand it better.